# SQL get the count of ids when timestamp difference is greater than 30

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have this following table data structure.
I need to find the number of SESSIONS.

SESSION is : For a userid, if multiple rows are there, then check the timestamp. If the **timestamp diffrence is less than 30**, consider it one session.

```
+---------+----------+
|userid   | timestamp|
+---------+----------+
|  1      | 10       |
|  1      | 11       |
|  1      | 55       |
|  2      | 65       |
+---------+----------+
```

In this example above, for ***userid 1*** the timestamp 10 and 11 is considered as a single session. But **(55-11 = 44) which is greater than 30**. So, it is another session.

1. So there are 2 sessions for userid 1 and
2. And there are 1 sessions for userid 2 and

**And overall there are 2+1= 3 sessions.** I only need to fetch this count. How to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you want an answer in Hive or MySQL?

Comment: I want it for hive. The basic idea would be same I guess? Tagged mySql to get the general SQL idea

Comment: Hive is quite limited compared to other versions of SQL.  For instance, it doesn't offer subqueries in the `from` clause and has other limitations.

Comment: a question here my friend, when `userid` is `1` you must do something like this `55 - 11 = 44`, is it possible if you do `55 - 10`, i mean do `max(timestamp) - min(timestamp)`?

Comment: @Hamidreza : No, can not do MAX-MIN, because I am tracking the continuity.

Comment: and another question if `timestamp` was `30` exchange of `11` then `userid1` gots just 1 sessions?

Comment: @Hamidreza :yes, right...one session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query work fine:

```
SELECT COUNT(FINAL_TAB.userid) + SUM(FINAL_TAB.FIN) FINAL_RESULT FROM
(SELECT TAB2.userid,SUM(CNT) FIN FROM
(SELECT TAB1.userid,CASE WHEN HA > 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END CNT FROM
(SELECT Q1.userid,CASE WHEN Q1.userid = Q2.userid THEN Q2.timestamp - Q1.timestamp 
ELSE 0 END HA FROM 
(SELECT @v1 := @v1 + 1 RN,TABLE1.* FROM TABLE1 JOIN(SELECT @v1 := 0)V1)Q1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT @v2 := @v2 + 1 RN,TABLE1.* FROM TABLE1 JOIN(SELECT @v2 := 0)V2)Q2
ON Q1.RN = Q2.RN - 1)TAB1)TAB2 GROUP BY TAB2.userid)FINAL_TAB;
```

**[ORACLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d973f/1)

[MS SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56044/3)

[MYSQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/560449/13)

[PostgreSQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/56044/1)**

The most important thing in this query is that i add `row number` as `RN` to the first table and i create `Q1` and `Q2` then i join `Q1` and `Q2` on `Q1.RN = Q2.RN - 1`, there for we got **current** `timestamp` as `Q1.timestamp` and **next** `timestamp` as `Q2.timestamp`,and this query works on each kinds of `RDBMS` just with changing `ROW Number` functions.